# document.getElementById("something").value not working for <Select> with <option> not working after Locker Service enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, locker-service

The document.getElementById("something").value in my controller on HTML tag  with  is not working after Locker Service is enabled. I did console.log() and it's returning nothing.

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhi

HTML markup :

```
                       <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> 
                            <select class="form-control picklist" onchange="{!c.filteredProducts}" name="Discount__c" id="discount">
                                <option value="">Discount</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

And the javascript function:

```
filteredProducts: function(component,event,helper) 
{
    var discount =document.getElementById("discount").value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhiram, will you please share the relevant pieces of HTML markup?

Comment: You just want to access the DOM element? Then try giving an aura id and then access the same by    component.find('auraid').getElement()

Comment: Hi Trevor, I have added the HTML markup as well as the javascript snippet where I am trying to get the value.

Comment: @AbhiramSheshadri To follow up, the original issue of 'value' property not being present on the select element is targeted to be fixed in an upcoming patch. Most likely in a week or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Lightning* way to do this would be to have:

.cmp

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="discount" change="{!c.filteredProducts}"  class="form-control picklist">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="" label="Discount" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="10" label="10" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" label="20" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="30" label="30" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="40" label="40" />
    </ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
filteredProducts: function(component, event, helper) {
    var discount = component.find("discount").get("v.value");
    console.log(discount);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do something like this it's may help you:

```
<apex:page>
      <select id='SelectId' onchange='changeVal()'>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <Script>
        function changeVal(){
            console.log(':::',document.getElementById("SelectId").value);
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The question is regarding lightning components and not VF